# Converting Dataframe from seconds to minutes works interactively but not with csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I've seen many questions and answers on how to convert column data in seconds into minutes, using pd.to_timedelta.   Unfortunately, this works for me only when the data is entered manually, but not if it comes from a csv file.

This is the contents of the csv file:

```
"Time"
"s"
"0.193"
"0.697"
"1.074"
"1.579"
"6.083"
"65.460"
"120.730"
"121.116"
"121.624"
```

I attempt to convert the seconds column to minutes via:

```
>> df = pd.read_csv("sec.csv", header = [0,1])
>> print (df.dtypes)

Time  s    float64
dtype: object

>> df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('float64')
>> print (df.dtypes)

Time  s    float64
dtype: object

>>> df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'], 'min')
TypeError: arg must be a string, timedelta, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

However, I don't get an error if I enter the data manually without the csv:

```
>>> csvdata  =  {'Time' : [ 0.193, 0.697, 1.074, 1.579, 6.083 , 65.460 , 120.730 , 121.116, 121.624 ]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=csvdata)
>>> print (df.dtypes)

Time    float64
dtype: object

>>> df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'], 'min')
```

I understand the csv is text, but with or without 'astype' the data type shows float64, so not sure the difference why the csv would have an error converting seconds to minutes.

Comment: in `CSV` you have double header `Time, s` - so you have to select correct column. Using `Time` it may gives `DataFrame` instead of `Series`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some functions work with many columns (`DataFrame`) (ie. `astype`) but `to_timedelta` needs single column (`Series`)

In CSV you have multi-header `Time,s` and you have to use `df['Time','s']` or `df[('Time','s')]` to get column (`Series`)

(sometimes works also `df['Time']['s']` - when you want to get column but not when you try to assign new value to column)

```
df[('Time','s')] = pd.to_timedelta(df[('Time','s')], 'min')
```

---

Full working code.

I use `io.StringIO` to simulate file in memory.

```
text = '''"Time"
"s"
"0.193"
"0.697"
"1.074"
"1.579"
"6.083"
"65.460"
"120.730"
"121.116"
"121.624"'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), header = [0,1])

print("['Time']    :", type(df['Time']))
print("['Time','s']:", type(df['Time','s']))

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

#df[('Time','s')] = pd.to_timedelta(df[('Time','s')], 'min')
df['Time','s'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time','s'], 'min')

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
['Time']    : <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
['Time','s']: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

--- before ---

      Time
         s
0    0.193
1    0.697
2    1.074
3    1.579
4    6.083
5   65.460
6  120.730
7  121.116
8  121.624

--- after ---

                    Time
                       s
0 0 days 00:00:11.580000
1 0 days 00:00:41.820000
2 0 days 00:01:04.440000
3 0 days 00:01:34.740000
4 0 days 00:06:04.980000
5 0 days 01:05:27.600000
6 0 days 02:00:43.800000
7 0 days 02:01:06.960000
8 0 days 02:01:37.440000
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!   Gotta admit though, that sometimes I do operations on the series with just the df['Time'] with no problem, then other times, like this one, it needed the df['Time', 's'].   Still haven't quite figured out all the nuances of pandas!

Comment: in file you have multi-header and then `df['Time']` gives `DataFrame`, not `Series` - and some functions can work with `DataFrame` but other needs exactly `Series`. So all depends on function which you used. And when you created code in `csvdata  =  {'Time' : [...]}` then it creates single-header and `df['Time']` gives `Series`. And all this makes difference. BTW: in code I used `print( type(df['Time']) )` to check if it gives me `DataFrame` or `Series`